Scheme-theoretic construction of tensor product of vector bundles on a scheme.
Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be locally free sheaves of finite rank (maybe works with coherent sheaves?). Let $E = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathcal{E}^\vee))$ denote the total space of $\mathcal{E}$ and ditto with $F$. My question is: can one define $E \otimes F$ (i.e. the total space of the tensor product of the sheaves) using only scheme-theoretic constructions, by which I mean without reference to $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$? For example, via a universal property? Or a functor-of-points?
Of course, one can brute force this, by looking at local trivialisations of $E$ and $F$ and multiplying their transition maps. But I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way?

I should clarify universal property in the category of schemes

The universal property is in the category of quasicoherent sheaves or similar and it is the usual one (the universal recipient of a bilinear map). I don't know that it really makes sense to ask for a universal property of the total space. What kind of answer are you looking for in the case that $X$ is a point?

Thanks for your response, I have changed the question. At the end of the day, I'm looking for a "clean" description of the tensor product - a universal property is what came to mind first, but I'm open to other ways.

The total space of a vector bundle does have a universal property. Let $p: E \to X$ be the total space of the vector bundle $\mathcal E$ on $X$.
The universal property of $E$ is: a map $f: Y \to E$ is the same as a map $\bar f: Y \to X$ and an $\mathcal O_X$-linear map $\mathcal E^\vee \to f_*\mathcal O_Y$. This follows since $p$ is an affine morphism and a ring homomorphism out of $\mathrm{Sym}(V)$ is the same as a linear map out of $V$.
Now this universal property for the total space is in terms of linear maps out of $\mathcal E^\vee$, so you can use the usual linear universal property of tensor product to formulate a universal property for the total space of the tensor product. Hope this helps.

Thank you. I think this is enough for me to work off for now.
